# Java equivalent of groovy's Object with(Closure) method

Tags: java, groovy

I'm looking for a nice way to do in Java (version 8) what is the equivalent of Groovy's [`with`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method on `Object`.

Say I have a class (done in Java, so I can use in each):

```
class MyClass {
  private String someVar;

  public void setSomeVar(String newVal) {
    this.someVar = newVal;
  }

  public String getSomeVar() {
    return this.someVar;
  }
}
```

In Groovy, I could then:

```
def mc = new MyClass().with {
  setSomeVar('Hello World!') // Yes, I'm using an explicit setter for clearer comparison
  it // return the instance
}
```

In Java though, the closest I can think of is to use the double brace initializer:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(){{
  setSomeVar("Hello World!");
}};
```

However [some advise against using the double brace initializer](http://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-the-double-brace-initializer/). And indeed, the lingering reference does cause me caution.

So, is there an alternative?

Comment: btw, for initialization in groovy it's easier to use `new MyClass(someVar: 'Hello World!')`

Comment: Indeed, this is a contrived example with focus on Java.

Comment: I understand. it's just in case if you're really using such code in groovy

Comment: For the initialization use case, the builder pattern is probably the closest thing available in Java. Of course, it's the responsibility of `MyClass` to implement that pattern. The `with` method comes for free with any type.

Comment: @bdkosher - indeed implementing an object creation pattern seems the only way I could do it - other than double brace. Just that it'd great to have either the default constructors from groovy (i.e. with parameterised arguments) or the `Object.with()` method. However even the `with` method is building on groovy's metaprogramming, so it's not just like I can concisely write a java implementation of it - I'd have to do some reflection and even then a class would need to inherit it. Oh well, it was worth checking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such construct in java that is an equivalent to groovy's `with`. The closest is the mentioned double brace initializer.

What are you trying to achieve? Describe the problem, maybe there's a ready-to-use pattern in java to solve it?

Comment: Thanks @Opal, you've basically confirmed the premise and what everyone else is saying. I guess I'm just missing Groovy having gone back to working on a pure Java project. As to what am I trying to achieve: I'm looking for concision and readability in Java code. But hey, that's why we have things like Groovy now. ;)